# Ansible: iterate over a results return value yum module

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible, nested-lists

Problem: I have many nodes that need package updates. Some of the nodes have these packages installed and some do not. 
The goal is to 
1. check if a package is installed using the yum module.
2. if package is installed and update is available then run yum update

I know this is easily done via command or shell but very inefficient.

```
  tasks:
  - name: check if packages are installed
    yum: list="{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - acpid
      - c-ares
      - automake
   register: packages


  - debug:
      var: packages
```

will produce 
[the results](https://pastebin.com/wmWN4Ca7)

What i want ansible to do is to update the package only when yum: list sees the package as installed and an upgrade available from the above results.

I'm not sure if that is possible using the yum module.

The quick and easy way would just to use command:

```
  tasks:
  - name: check if packages are installed
    command: yum update -y {{ item }}
    with_items:
      - acpid
      - c-ares 
      - automake
```

since yum update package will only update a package if it is installed.

Comment: Why not use the quick and easy way?

Answer (score 0):

The Ansible [loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html) documentation has a [section about using `register` in a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop).

Taking a look at the output of your `debug` task, you can see that your `packages` variable has a key named `results` that contains the results of your `with_items` loop in the first task.  The large structure looks like this:

```
{  
   "packages":{  
      "changed":false,
      "msg":"All items completed",
      "results":[  
         {  
            "item":"...",
            "results":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "item":"...",
            "results":[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Each individual result has a key `item` that contains the value of the loop iterator for that result, and a `results` key that contains the list of packages (possible empty) returned by the `list` option to the `yum` module.

With that in mind, you could loop over the results like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.item }}"
  with_items: "{{ packages.results }}"
  when: item.results
```

The `when` condition matches only those results for which the `list` operation returned a non-empty result.

To upgrade matching packages:

```
- yum:
    name: "{{ item.item }}"
    state: latest
  with_items: "{{ packages.results }}"
  when: item.results
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ansible.builtin.yum:` module already updates only if a package is installed.  You can loop over a list of items using the `loop:` directive, or if it's a short list, declare the variable within the task block and use the yum module's ability to operate over a list.  Like the quick and dirty version.

```
- name: update a list of packages
  yum:
    name: "{{ packagelist }}"
    state: latest
  vars:
    packagelist:
      - acpid
      - c-ares 
      - automake
```

Or, even simpler:

```
- name: update a list of packages
  yum:
    name:
      - acpid
      - c-ares 
      - automake
    state: latest
```

Many more examples are available and all the parameters are defined here:
[Ansible Docs article about yum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html)